# error "does not contain a definition for 'getProperty'" when trying to set property of generic typed object

Tags: c#, reflection

```
void myFunc<M>()
{
    dynamic uploadReq = (M)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(M));
    uploadReq.getProperty("Credentials").SetValue(null);
}
```

I have a function where I supply a type, an object of this type is created, and then a property on the object is set to null. I get an error

> MyCustomType does not contain a definition for 'getProperty'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you use `dynamic` here?

Comment: 'getProperty' - assuming this is as you've typed it, it should have a capital 'G'.

Comment: @sr28 same thing with capital G, no compile errors on either it looks like

Comment: @GuruStron it's a bit of code I got from somewhere else, what should I be doing?

Comment: I think regarding dynamic, it's more that you would normally use 'var' as this won't avoid compile time checking.

Comment: I also think you need uploadReq.GetType().GetProperty("Credentials").SetValue(null);

Comment: Try `M uploadReq = (M)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(M)); uploadReq.Credentials = null;`

Comment: @sr28 thanks that does seem to fix the original issue. but now SetValue() doesn't seem to work because it is not recognized. Any ideas?

Comment: It needs the object you're setting I think like this uploadReq.GetType().GetProperty("Credentials").SetValue(uploadReq, null);

Comment: @sr28 I think that was it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GetProperty its method of Type. Object has no it.
You can use this way:

1. call GetProperty from type
2. set value to object

   ```
   public static void  myFunc<M>()
    {
        dynamic uploadReq = (M)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(M));
        typeof(M).GetProperty("Credentials").SetValue(uploadReq, null);
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific snippet of code you don't need `dynamic` or reflection, because you know the type at compile time, just use the generic version of the `CreateInstance` method or even better the constructor of the type. This is faster and also provides compile time checks.

```
void myFunc<M>() where M : new()
{
   M uploadReq = new M();
   uploadReq.Credentials = null;
}
```

or

```
M uploadReq = Activator.CreateInstance<M>();
uploadReq.Credentials = null;
```